# jQuery Tools Validator - regex test - exclude just letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-tools

i'm trying to validate a field to include everything except letters but the following only works on the first character i enter. So if i enter '123a' the test method returns true.

```
$.tools.validator.fn("input#Phone", "Please enter a valid phone number.", function(input, value) {  
    var pass;
    var rgx = /[^a-z]/gi;

    if ( rgx.test(value) 
         || (value == "") 
         || (value == $(input).attr("placeholder"))) {  

        $(input).removeClass("invalid");            
        pass = true;            
    } else {                    
        $(input).addClass("invalid");           
        pass = false;       
    }

    return pass;
}
```

Comment: Try this: var rgx=/[a-z]*/gi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for only numeric:

   ```
     RegExp(/^[^a-zA-Z]$/i)
   ```
2. for phone number you can use

   ```
    RegExp(/^[0-9 -()+]{6,20}$/i)
   ```

Comment: Don't forget periods.  And what about extensions?

Comment: if you want to allow ext characters use                            RegExp(/^[0-9ext -()+]{1,25}$/i)

Answer (score 1):

You're only matching against a single character.

```
/^[^a-z]$/i
```

This ensures that the entire string is non-letters.